# If a homomorphism is surjective it cannot be trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

My group theory is a bit rusty, but I recall such a property existing. Is this true, if so, can anyone give me some hints as to how to prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an additional hypothesis. If a homomorphism *whose codomain is a nontrivial group* is surjective then it is nontrivial (this is immediate from the fact that the trivial homomorphism by definition takes on only one value), but of course the trivial homomorphism to the trivial group is surjective.

Comment: Thank you. So can this be extended to saying any homomorphism whose codomain is a nontrivial group cannot be trivial if at least one element does not map to the identity element?

Comment: @CBBAM I mean, that's just the definition of the trivial homomorphism: the trivial homomorphism $G\rightarrow H$ is the homomorphism sending every element of $G$ to the identity of $H$. The point is that this means that the only way for the trivial homomorphism to be surjective is if $H$ consists of just its identity element.

Comment: Ahhh yes now I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a group. Consider

$$\begin{align}
\varphi: G &\to \{e\}\\
g & \mapsto e.
\end{align}$$

Then for any $g,h\in G$, we have $\varphi (gh)=e=ee=\varphi(g)\varphi(h)$, so $\varphi$ is a homomorphism.

Also, we have, for $e\in \{e\}$, there exists a $k\in G$ such that $e=\varphi(k)$ by definition of $\varphi$; namely, we can take $e_G=k$. So $\varphi$ is surjective.

But, clearly, $\varphi$ is trivial.